# RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29 Unbalanced calls start/end for tag 5

Tags: react-native

> 2015-10-28 22:12:35.305 [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29]
> Unbalanced calls start/end for tag 5 2015-10-28 22:12:35.305
>
> [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29] Unbalanced calls start/end
> for tag 5 2015-10-28 22:12:35.306
>
> [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29] Unbalanced calls start/end
> for tag 5 2015-10-28 22:12:35.346
>
> [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29] Unbalanced calls start/end
> for tag 5 2015-10-28 22:12:35.347
>
> [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29] Unbalanced calls start/end
> for tag 5 2015-10-28 22:12:35.348
>
> [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29] Unbalanced calls start/end
> for tag 5 2015-10-28 22:12:35.348
>
> [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29] Unbalanced calls start/end
> for tag 5 2015-10-28 22:12:35.349
>
> [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29] Unbalanced calls start/end
> for tag 5 2015-10-28 22:12:35.350
>
> [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29] Unbalanced calls start/end
> for tag 5 2015-10-28 22:12:35.351
>
> [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29] Unbalanced calls start/end
> for tag 5 2015-10-28 22:12:35.354
>
> [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29] Unbalanced calls start/end
> for tag 5

While runing, it prints this in log.
What does it mean?

Comment: same thing happening to me. Also, after fiddling around in plist.info this stuff appeared. Maybe thats an issue? Figuring out, what causes this...

2015-11-27 23:10:55.340 [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:29] Unbalanced calls start/end for tag 5

Comment: I am using react-native-camera and enabled background modes when this happened.